# Combinatorial Identity involving Binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics

I’m struggling to prove this identity:
$$
  \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \frac{1}{k+1} = (2^{n+1}-1) \frac{1}{n+1}
$$
No clue where to start but my intuition on the RHS says that there is a n+1-element set and we want to put them into some number of distinguishable cells such that the cells are nonempty.

Any help or advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that by the Binomial Theorem,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k=(1+x)^n.$$
**Integrate** both sides with respect to $x$, from $x=0$ to $x=1$.

Answer (score 5):

You have that

$$\frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k}=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k+1}.$$

Thus

$$2^{n+1}-1=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n+1}{k+1}=(n+1)\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k+1}\binom{n}{k},$$ from where you get the desired equality.